# Deploy SignalR server in Ubuntu using Docker

Tags: c#, docker, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying deploy a signalR server in docker . Without docker this was connected with test client in local. But now it is showing Cors error and not connecting from local client

My program.cs

```
using chat_server.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsPolicy", build =>
{
    build.WithOrigins("http://[serverIP]:8100", "https://[serverIP]:8100", "http://[serverIP]:80", "https://[serverIP]:80")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials();
}));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("corsPolicy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");

app.Run();
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8100
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["chat_server.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./chat_server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "chat_server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "chat_server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "chat_server.dll"]
```

My demo client connection string, running from local

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://[serverIP]:8100/chathub")  // Update with your hub URL
            .build();
```

from console i am having the issue is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://185.100.232.17:8100/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

Comment: Try putting  `app. UseCors("corsPolicy"); ` behind `app. UseHttpsRedirection(); `and tell us about your test results.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue myself

changed the Program.cs , as

```
app.UseCors(cp => cp
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
    .AllowCredentials());
```

docker run command is

```
docker run -d -p 8100:8100 --name [docker_name] [image_name]
```